# Dynamic/Static Resource Mapping (Terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

Having trouble figuring something out and wanted to run it by the community here. Its probably straight forward, I'm struggling to find an answer.

I'm creating KMS keys, S3 buckets, KMS aliases.

I am using a locals map to establish a few variable using other variables, so a variables.tf doesn't really fit. My main question is highlighted by ????? below.

How do I map a resource to a specific returned value within another resource? So for instance only certain keys will be used on certain buckets. How would I create a check within the resource to only assign a KMS key that I want for each bucket its creating.

```
locals {
  buckets = {
    "1" = { 
      name    = "1", 
      kms_key = false 
    },
    "2" = { 
      name    = "2", 
      kms_key = false 
    },
    "3"     = { 
      name    = "3", 
      kms_key = false 
    },
    "4"     = { 
      name    = "4", 
      kms_key = false 
    },
    "5"        = { 
      name    = "5", 
      kms_key = false 
    },
    "6"          = { 
      name    = "6", 
      kms_key = false 
    }
  }
  keys = {
    "1"     = {
      description = "1"
      alias       = "alias/1-key"
    },
    "il5"      = {
      description = "2"
      alias       = "alias/2-key"
    },
    "ebs"      = {
      description = "3"
      alias       = "alias/3-key"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  for_each = local.keys

  description             = each.value.description
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  deletion_window_in_days = 30
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "this" {
  for_each = local.keys

  name          = each.value.alias
  target_key_id = ??????
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  for_each = local.buckets

  bucket = each.value.name
  acl    = "private"

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
        kms_master_key_id = ??????
      }
    }
  }
```

I was thinking something like this? And yes, I get the syntax is way invalid, just giving an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish without a full understanding of how to do it.

```
server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
        kms_master_key_id = {
            if this bucket = this key,
            if this bucket = this key,
            if this bucket = this key,
            etc
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can try set `each.key`.

Here is an example

```
locals {
  buckets = {
    "1" = {
      name    = "1",
      kms_key = false
    },
    "2" = {
      name    = "2",
      kms_key = false
    }
  }
  keys = {
    "1" = {
      description = "1"
      alias       = "alias/1-key"
    },
    "2" = {
      description = "2"
      alias       = "alias/2-key"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  for_each = local.keys

  description             = each.value.description
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  deletion_window_in_days = 30
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "this" {
  for_each = local.keys

  name          = each.value.alias
  target_key_id = aws_kms_key.key[each.key].id
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  for_each = local.buckets

  bucket = each.value.name
  acl    = "private"

  server_side_encryption_configuration {
    rule {
      apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
        sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
        kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.key[each.key].id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works, but only if `locals.buckets` and `locals.keys` have the same keys name (`1,2,3,etc`)

Comment: Not sure that will do what I’m trying to do. Essentially I’m creating 6 buckets and 3 KMS keys/aliases. Only assigning a specific key to a few of those buckets, and another key to a few others. Just not sure how to dynamically allocate those values and map them on the fly like that. I’d rather not have to create a key per bucket, and statically assign the keys to the buckets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting by adjusting the initial data structures slightly so that the relationships between the buckets and the keys is explicit:

```
locals {
  buckets = tomap({
    "1" = { 
      name    = "1" 
      kms_key = "1" 
    }
    "2" = { 
      name    = "2" 
      kms_key = null
    }
    "3" = { 
      name    = "3"
      kms_key = "il5"
    }
    "4" = { 
      name    = "4" 
      kms_key = null 
    }
    "5" = { 
      name    = "5" 
      kms_key = null
    }
    "6" = { 
      name    = "6" 
      kms_key = "ebs"
    }
  })
  keys = {
    "1"     = {
      description = "1"
      alias       = "alias/1-key"
    },
    "il5"      = {
      description = "2"
      alias       = "alias/2-key"
    },
    "ebs"      = {
      description = "3"
      alias       = "alias/3-key"
    }
  }
}
```

Here I've changed the `kms_key` attribute of each bucket to be either a lookup key into `local.keys`, or `null` to indicate that this bucket won't have a key at all.

The KMS key and its alias are a good situation to employ [chaining between resources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html#chaining-for_each-between-resources), which means to use the value representing on resource as the `for_each` for another:

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "key" {
  for_each = local.keys

  description             = each.value.description
  enable_key_rotation     = true
  deletion_window_in_days = 30
}

resource "aws_kms_alias" "this" {
  for_each = aws_kms_key.key

  name          = local.keys[each.key].alias
  target_key_id = each.value.id
}
```

Declaring the relationship in this way makes it explicit that there should be one alias per key, which is helpful both to humans (can see the intended relationship) and also to Terraform, which can see that it should expect aliases to be added/removed at the same time as their keys are.

That then leaves the S3 buckets and their optional connection with KMS keys declared above:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  for_each = local.buckets

  bucket = each.value.name
  acl    = "private"

  dynamic "server_side_encryption_configuration" {
    for_each = each.value.kms_key[*]
    content {
      rule {
        apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
          sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
          kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.key[server_side_encryption_configuration.value].id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this case I used a [`dynamic` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) to conditionally generate a `server_side_encryption_configuration` block only for the buckets that have a non-null `kms_key` value. This also uses the `[*]` splat operator to [treat `each.value.kms_key` as if it were a list](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html#single-values-as-lists), where it'll produce an empty list for a `null` or a one-element list for a non-null string.

Inside the `content` block, `server_side_encryption_configuration.value` is the value from the `for_each`, and so with `each.value.kms_key` that's the key name value directly. Those strings are supposed to correlate with keys in `local.keys`, and thus with keys of `aws_kms_key.key`, and so we can look up the dynamically-chosen ID for each of the selected keys.